# OpenMP C++ - How to parallelize this function?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'd like to parallelize this function but I'm new with open mp and I'd be grateful if someone could help me :

```
void my_function(float** A,int nbNeurons,int nbOutput, float* p, float* amp){
   float t=0;
   for(int r=0;r<nbNeurons;r++){
      t+=p[r];
   }

   for(int i=0;i<nbOutput;i++){
      float coef=0;
      for(int r=0;r<nbNeurons;r++){
       coef+=p[r]*A[r][i];
      }
   amp[i]=coef/t;
   }
}
```

I don't know how to parallelize it properly because of the double loop for, for the moment, I only thought about doing a :
 `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:t)`

But I think it is not the best way to get the computing faster through openMp.

Thank in advance,

Comment: Don't let the double loop scare you. You can throw an OpenMP `pragma` over that as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: we need to know context. Where does your profiler tell you the most time is spent?

In general, coarse grained parallellization works best, so as @Alex said: parallellize the outer for loop.

```
void my_function(float** A,int nbNeurons,int nbOutput, float* p, float* amp)
{
    float t=0;
    for(int r=0;r<nbNeurons;r++)
        t+=p[r];

#pragma parallel omp for 
    for(int i=0;i<nbOutput;i++){
        float coef=0;
        for(int r=0;r<nbNeurons;r++){
            coef+=p[r]*A[r][i];
        }
        amp[i]=coef/t;
    }
}
```

Depending on the actual volumes, it may be interesting to calculate t in the background, and move the division out of the parallel loop:

```
void my_function(float** A,int nbNeurons,int nbOutput, float* p, float* amp)
{
    float t=0;
#pragma omp parallel shared(amp)
    {
#pragma omp single nowait // only a single thread executes this
        {
            for(int r=0;r<nbNeurons;r++)
                t+=p[r];
        }

#pragma omp for 
        for(int i=0;i<nbOutput;i++){
            float coef=0;
            for(int r=0;r<nbNeurons;r++){
                coef+=p[r]*A[r][i];
            }
            amp[i]=coef;
        }

#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp master // only a single thread executes this
        {
            for(int i=0; i<nbOutput; i++){
                amp[i] /= t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** untested code. OMP has tricky semantics sometimes, so I might have missed a 'shared' declaration there. Nothing a profiler won't quickly notify you about, though.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers, is that okay to parellelize the higher loop even if I modify the value inside ? I mean it is a += and not a simple affection =. Thanks. Parellelization is so tricky...

Comment: There is only += and /= in exclusive sections there.  The coef is not shared across threads

Comment: I would 
EITHER { add "nowait" at the end of the omp single pragma, and "#pragma barrier" at the very end of the function. }
OR {
no "nowait", but put the "/t" back into the parrallelized for loop. }

Comment: @natchouf Good point. Like I said, the code was off the top of my head, and I don't use OpenMP regularly enough to remember the specifics. What you propose is exactly what I intended to show. To the OP ***profile profile profile*** - /then/ optimize

Comment: I tried to implement it but the parallelization gave me a wrong value to the final output "amp", thank you by the way maybe I should try the barrier.

Comment: @kuider I've included the simpler approach, that I expect to be more than enough, but again, I lack all information about input volumes and target machine to judge that. I suggest you take the simples approach that gets you the performance you need. This also means **don't use openmp** if it isn't required :)